# Import function manually

Tags: python

I'm beginner in python, and i tried to understand the **from ... import ...** statement.
I surprised to found that we can import function manually, and i want to ask you if it is legal.
My module:

```
**my_module.py**

def func1():
    print 10

def func2():
    print 20
```

My program:

```
import sys
from my_module import func1

func2() ==> ERROR!

globals()["func2"] = sys.modules["my_module"].func2

func2() ==> Printing 20!
```

Comment: you need to explain more about your problem !

Comment: do you mean `sys.modules["my_module"].func2()`?

Comment: Obviously it's legal, since you are doing it and Python isn't complaining. I can't imagine *why* you would do it though.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes. mistake.

Comment: @yuvalhuck, anyway besides that there is no advantage and it makes your code less readable so the short answer is no never do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking about this line:

```
globals()["func2"] = sys.modules["name"].func2
```

Is it "legal"? Sure. I mean, the Python police won't come arrest you for it.

Is it a good idea? No. If you're just importing a function, better to do it the way you did with `func1`. Easier to read and understand for folks who come look at your code later; better for compatibility with static analysis tools; less likely to break in future versions of Python; etc.

If you're making a module which does something "magic" in Python like wrapping another module's functions or something, then you might want to use the capability to dynamically import and name a function that way. But for general day-to-day programming, avoid it.

Comment: that line won't actually do anything except throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, some pythonians will chew your leg off if they see that. It is very non-pythonic. `import` is a runtime statement (I mean, everything is), so there's no reason at all to use `sys.modules` version.

Comment: I believe the question is about importing a function using `sys.modules` as shown in the code (though it could have been described better).

Comment: @interjay yeah, that got me confused, you are right, will edit.